# STRtree implementation output contains random points

Tags: java, r-tree, jts

I'm using JTS with Netbeans to implement STRtrees . I'm trying to build an STRtree for a set of points( coordinates ) . Here is my code :

```
package example;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Envelope;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.index.ArrayListVisitor;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.index.strtree.STRtree;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Getting input from the user as points

    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    Coordinate coord = new Coordinate( 1, 1 );
    Point point=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 3,2 );
    Point point2=gf.createPoint( coord );
    coord = new Coordinate( 2,4 );
    Point point3=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 4,1 );
    Point point4=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 5,2);
    Point point5=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 4,5);
    Point point6=gf.createPoint( coord );
    coord = new Coordinate( 3,6 );
    Point point7=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 1,6 );
    Point point8=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 6,2 );
    Point point9=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 7,1 );
    Point point10=gf.createPoint( coord );
    coord = new Coordinate( 6,4 );
    Point point11=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 9,2);
    Point point12=gf.createPoint( coord );
    coord = new Coordinate( 3,8);
    Point point13=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 1,7);
    Point point14=gf.createPoint( coord );
    coord = new Coordinate( 3,7 );
    Point point15=gf.createPoint( coord );
     coord = new Coordinate( 5,7 );
    Point point16=gf.createPoint( coord );
    //Building the str object
    STRtree strTree=new STRtree();
    //inserting the points into the tree
    strTree.insert(point.getEnvelopeInternal(), point);
    strTree.insert(point2.getEnvelopeInternal(), point2);
    strTree.insert(point3.getEnvelopeInternal(), point3);
     strTree.insert(point4.getEnvelopeInternal(), point4);
    strTree.insert(point5.getEnvelopeInternal(), point5);
    strTree.insert(point6.getEnvelopeInternal(), point6);
     strTree.insert(point7.getEnvelopeInternal(), point7);
    strTree.insert(point8.getEnvelopeInternal(), point8);
    strTree.insert(point9.getEnvelopeInternal(), point9);
     strTree.insert(point10.getEnvelopeInternal(), point10);
    strTree.insert(point11.getEnvelopeInternal(), point11);
    strTree.insert(point12.getEnvelopeInternal(), point12);
     strTree.insert(point13.getEnvelopeInternal(), point13);
    strTree.insert(point14.getEnvelopeInternal(), point14);
    strTree.insert(point15.getEnvelopeInternal(), point15);
    strTree.insert(point16.getEnvelopeInternal(), point16);
    //Building the tree
    strTree.build();
    Coordinate coord2 = new Coordinate( 0,0 );
    Coordinate coord3 = new Coordinate( 5,5);
     Envelope e1=new Envelope(coord2,coord3);
     List List1 = strTree.query(e1);
     System.out.println(List1);
}
}
```

The code complies and runs, but I was expecting the points to get sorted in this order( roots->children->leaves ) . But my output contains random points in the enveloped region. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The R-tree *stores all points in the leaf nodes.*

The "order" that you are looking for does not exist; all results *must* be from the leaves.

The JTS API looks like it's painfully expensive. Coordinates wrapped in Points wrapped in Envelopes. You may want to have a look at ELKI, which I found to have very high performance. In contrast to popular belief, I have found ELKI R-trees (at least when STR bulk loaded) to still work very well in 32 dimensions (popular knowledge claims that R-trees only work up to 10 dimensions).

Comment: I just need a 2-D tree, to show the root, children and the leaves correctly( if that's not possible, at least the order in which my leaves get enveloped, the coordinates are getting displayed randomly). Is there any other software I could use, or could you tweak this code to get my output ?.

Comment: Well, I don't *know* "your output". As an R-tree will not have a point as root node, *no* R-tree will give you a point as root.